# Консольное приложение: кредитный калькулятор. Неверный расчёт значений?

Tags: python, python-3.x, логика, калькулятор, формулы

В общем, нужно решить задачу по питону - создать консольное приложение.

Суть очень простая - нужно написать кредитный калькулятор, который принимает следующие данные:

- Сумма кредита(изначальная) - `summ`;
- Процентная ставка в год - `proc`;
- Срок выплаты - `time`.

Схема выплаты - [дифференцированная](https://credits.ru/publications/376892/annuitetnyj-ili-differencirovannyj-platezhi-chto-vygodnee-zaemschiku) (можете погуглить), коротко:
проценты начисляются по фактическому остатку задолженности, поэтому каждый последующий платёж будет меньше предыдущего.

---

***P.S.** Так что задача вполне реалистичная)*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И далее эта программа должна вывести платеж за каждый месяц, [типа так](http://calculator-credit.ru/calculator.php):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня, пока, получился код, который очень близок по значениям, но все равно он пишет значения несколько больше, чем нужно. 
И в итоге, сумма долга(`summ`), становится меньше нуля. 
Например, `-400`, т.е. клиент отдаст банку на `400` рублей больше, чем должен, хотя как это происходит не понятно:

(Я для отладки вывожу `summ(сумма кредита)` и она получается отрицательной, хотя должна быть **`0`**, когда долг погашен.)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Полный код тут: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AsmxJIjWfgIxU3DA1TWTvqDAiSutdqQ2/view?usp=sharing

Код расчёта платежей:

```
month_main_pay=(summ/time) # Выплата по основному долгу в месяц
cicl=1 # Платеж №

while (cicl!=time+1): # Рассчет платежей 
    summ+=((summ/100*(proc))/12) # Начисление процентов к задолжности
    month_procent_pay=(summ/100*proc/12) #Выплата этих процентов в месяц
    print("\nПлатеж",cicl,":", (int(month_main_pay+month_procent_pay)),"руб." ) #Вывод платежа и суммы в сосноль
    summ-=(month_main_pay+month_procent_pay) #Вычет платежа из суммы задолжности
    cicl=cicl+1 #Добавление номера цикла
    itog=itog+(month_main_pay+month_procent_pay) #Всего выплачено
```

Как нужно изменить код, чтобы расчёты проводились верно?

Comment: Как изменить код? Очень просто: вместо картинки набрать нормальный код и нормальную таблицу, разместить это в заглавном сообщении. И этим показать, что Вы хоть что-то сами делаете.

Comment: О какой таблице идет речь? 
А код этой программы я полностью сам писал, так что "показать, что Вы хоть что-то сами делаете" имеет непонятный смысл. Я лично не вижу никаких препятствий к понимаю того, что мне нужно.

Comment: >>Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Выкладывая картинки, Вы тем самым становитесь похожим на школяра-двоешника, который где-то заснял таблицу, код, выложил в сообщение и ждет решение, чтобы закрыть "хвост". Поэтому - в вопросе максимум своего, выстраданного...

Comment: А я и не скрываю, что я заснял таблицу. На "типа так" стоит гиперссылка. Я результат в консоль вывожу. Мне цифры важны(т.е. формула), как понятно из названия, а не вид вывода. А код на выложенных картинках не отличается от кода вставленного текстом. Суть не меняется.

Comment: @LuminoDiode Разница между кодом на картинке и кодом в виде текста в том, что последний можно скопировать себе и работать с ним. Код на картинке никто вручную набирать не будет, поэтому шансы на ответ в этом случае стремятся к нулю, а на получение минусов - к единице.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
class BankInterest():
    def __init__(self, summ, perc, period):
        self.summ   = summ
        self.period = period
        self.perc   = perc

    def diff_int(self):
        arr = []
        mp_cnt = self.period * 12
        rest = self.summ
        mp_real = self.summ / (self.period * 12.0)
        while mp_cnt != 0:
            mp = mp_real + (rest * self.perc / 1200)
            arr.append(round(mp, 2))
            rest = rest - mp_real
            mp_cnt = mp_cnt - 1
        return arr, round(sum(arr), 2)

#                   Сумма,  процент, срок(год)
diff = BankInterest(1000000,  15,      1).diff_int()

for i,v in enumerate(diff):
    if i==0:
        for j,p in enumerate(v):
            print("Платеж {:7d} : {:.2f} руб.".format(j+1,p))
    else:
        print("Всего выплачено: {:.2f} руб.".format(v))


Платеж       1 : 95833.33 руб.
Платеж       2 : 94791.67 руб.
Платеж       3 : 93750.00 руб.
Платеж       4 : 92708.33 руб.
Платеж       5 : 91666.67 руб.
Платеж       6 : 90625.00 руб.
Платеж       7 : 89583.33 руб.
Платеж       8 : 88541.67 руб.
Платеж       9 : 87500.00 руб.
Платеж      10 : 86458.33 руб.
Платеж      11 : 85416.67 руб.
Платеж      12 : 84375.00 руб.
Всего выплачено: 1081250.00 руб.
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Эникейщик предоставьте  пожалуйста ваш расчет.

Comment: @Эникейщик я даже не обратил внимание, что в примере процентная ставка 10, а в моем примере 15 :)  Подставте ставку 10 и все станет как по вашему :)  `diff = BankInterest(1000000, 10, 1).diff_int()`

Comment: Ок, тогда да :)

Comment: Спасибо. Проанализировав ваш код нашел логическую ошибку в своем. Переписал правильно.

Comment: @LuminoDiode  так потихоньку и до аннуитетных платежей доберемся :)